# How to select the using table name into a select?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using this command to take the C_DIV column from all these tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT C_DIV FROM TBL_TASK UNION
SELECT DISTINCT C_DIV FROM TBL_DATAMART_SUMMARY UNION
SELECT DISTINCT C_DIV FROM MMS_DIVI
```

and a lot of more others tables.

from this output I get just the C_DIV column, with all the information that I needed.

I would like to know if there is some way to get a column with the  of each using table, so instead of getting just the column C_DIV, I would get C_DIV and TABLE_FROM

Exemple

```
C010    TBL_TASK 
C017    TBL_TASK 
C020    TBL_TASK 
C025    TBL_DATAMART_SUMMARY 
C027    TBL_DATAMART_SUMMARY 
C028    TBL_DATAMART_SUMMARY 
C034    TBL_DATAMART_SUMMARY 
C035    TBL_TASK 
C037    TBL_TASK
C050    MMS_DIVI
```

Comment: What about it was 100 tables? I thought there was some function like table_name(), to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just add it into the union:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C_DIV, 'TBL_TASK' as which FROM TBL_TASK UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT C_DIV, 'TBL_DATAMART_SUMMARY' FROM TBL_DATAMART_SUMMARY UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT C_DIV, 'MMS_DIVI' FROM MMS_DIVI;
```

Note that I also changed the `union` to `union all`.  There cannot be duplicates between the different subqueries, so there is no reason to incur the overhead of removing the duplicates.  `Union all` is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just the table name?  I'd hard code it in each union:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C_DIV , 'TBL_Task' as tablename FROM TBL_TASK UNION
SELECT DISTINCT C_DIV , 'TBL_DATAMARTSUMMARY' FROM TBL_DATAMART_SUMMARY UNION
SELECT DISTINCT C_DIV , 'MMS_DIVI' FROM MMS_DIVI
```